# datepicker is not a function (bootstrap datepicker)

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use Bootstrap datepicker in my project. I include following scripts and styles:

```html
<link href="{{ url('/datepicker/css/datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="{{ url('/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url('/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
```

Field for entering date:

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
    <input type="text" id="processdate" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Processing Date..." name="processdate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: '-180d',
        endDate: '+1d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I open the page, I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (register:135)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
```

Where is the mistake?
I used the code from here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lro8kxjx/6/

Comment: did you check your console? there is some message there?

Comment: I noticed, that there was included some js file in the page by default (I use Laravel):
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
When I commented out this string, I got another error.

Comment: Console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.parseDate (bootstrap-datepicker.js:393)
    at Datepicker.update (bootstrap-datepicker.js:161)
    at new Datepicker (bootstrap-datepicker.js:84)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datepicker.js:341)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.$.fn.datepicker (bootstrap-datepicker.js:336)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (register:135)
    at j (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)

Comment: I change links to bootstrap-datepicker to:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
and the datepicker works fine now. But I don't understand, why the datepicker doesn't work with files, which I downloaded from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/